# Format text field as user is typing, dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a `text_field_tag` that allows the user to enter an amount. How do I format this value dynamically, as the user is typing? For example, if the user enters "5000", it must display as "5,000".

Comment: Use a keypress event handler that *notes the current cursor position and restores it* after doing the required formatting - because a user may be trying to edit the beginning or middle of an existing value.

Comment: Use .keyup() with javascript regex.

Comment: Would you like to use any plugin for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think it in a straightforward way, we can just replace the current val with the ***formatted*** value. The performance is not expensive in this case, even using a for-loop multiple times (between formatting and deformatting).

For replacing text, I don't use regex because we need to find/match the text ***from the right***, so to use regex I think we need to reverse the text first, apply the regex replacement and reverse the result back. This is much worse than simply looping and replacing.

Here is the code:

***HTML***:

```
<input type="text"/>
<button> Show value </button>
```

***JS***:

```
var format = function(text) {
  var f = "";
  for(var i = text.length - 1; i >=0; i--){
    f = text[i] + f;
    var k = text.length - i;
    if(k % 3 == 0 && i > 0){
      f = "," + f;
    }
  }
  return f;
}
//defomratting the text to get the actual value
var deformat = function(text) {
  return text.replace(/,/g, "");
}

$("input").on("input", function(e){
  var s = this.selectionStart;
  var rawVal = $(this).val();
  var clen = rawVal.length;
  val = deformat(rawVal);
  var f = format(val);
  s += f.length - clen;
  $(this).val(f);
  //set the selection to ensure that it's not changed during typing.
  this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = s;
});

$("button").click(function(){
  alert(deformat($("input").val()));
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bkodsd5j/1)

Answer (score 1):

You could use Jquery Mask Plugin really easy to integrate and it will bring a lot of masks you can use.  Also will sava tons of time.
i.e.

```
$('.money').mask('000.000.000.000.000,00', {reverse: true});
```

https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/